# Where do I need to register my new Symfony controller test?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

Symfony 3.3 automatically generated an empty test for my new controller. It lives at `src/AppBundle/Tests/Controller/PairGalleryControllerTest.php`

Now I want to actually run the contents. They look like this:

```
public function testIndex()
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/pair-gallery/1');

    $content = $client->getResponse()->getContent();

    $this->assertContains('NeedleShouldFail', $content);
}
```

... but when I run my test suite with `bin/phpunit` I find that all tests pass. This new test is clearly not being run.

**Where do I need to register my new test in order for it to run?**

====

Edit: Here is the content of my phpunit.xml.dist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <!--
            <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
        -->
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: check the `phpunit.xml.dist` and the `composer.json` files in order to understand where the test folder and files are find (feel free to post the content of that files)

Comment: Thanks, Matteo. I have now added the content of that XML file.